# texi2dvi does not run biber/bibtex

Tags: biblatex, pdftex, biber, texi2dvi

I use `biblatex` for references. When I run `PDFLATEX='pdflatex --shell-escape -synctex=1 -file-line-error' texi2dvi -p foo.tex', I receive:

```
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                smooth_extremes
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

I thought that texi2dvi takes care of running bibtex/biber (?)

Comment: You are useing `biblatex` without an option `backend=bibtex`. `biblatex` does use `biber` (better) for creating the bibliography as standard. As I know `texi2dvi` uses `bibtex`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are useing `biblatex` without an option `backend=bibtex`. 
`biblatex` does use `biber` (better) for creating the bibliography as standard. As I know `texi2dvi` uses `bibtex`.

Answer (score 1):

For others who find this question, `biber` is supported by more recent versions of `texi2dvi` (at least the version in CTAN at time of writing) which is:

```
texi2dvi (GNU Texinfo 5.2) 

Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

`texi2dvi` from GNU Texinfo 6.5 (latest version available at time of writing) also works.