# How to get multiple bibliographies with biblatex with option backend=bibtex?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I am trying to create a bibliography (with `biblatex`) at the end of each chapter.
Something like this should work, but I don't see any bibliographies printed:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[
backend=bibtex,% ... what texi2dvi uses (with = biber it works)
style=authoryear,
refsection=chapter]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{bib.bib}
@article{A,
   author = {TeX, L.},
   journal = {Journal of LaTeX questions},
   pages = {1--10},
   title = {{Minimal title}},
   volume = {1},
   number = {1},
   year = {2011}}
@article{B,
   author = {La, T.},
   journal = {Journal of LaTeX questions},
   pages = {21--31},
   title = {{Minimal title}},
   volume = {1},
   number = {1},
   year = {2012}}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\cite{A}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\chapter{Chapter 2}
\cite{B}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{document}
```

If I use `backend=biber` it works. I am wondering whether there is still a solution
based on `backend=bibtex` as I (and co-authors) am compiling with `texi2dvi` which is based on `bibtex`. Could one perhaps create categories for each chapter? (categories don't seem to require `biber`).

Comment: You need to run `bibtex` on multiple files, not the main file. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128201/87678

Comment: ... okay, thanks, so *also* with `bibtex`, `texi2dvi` will not do the job automatically (unless one would go with categories but I'm not sure how to define a category containing all the references from a chapter).

Comment: Are you sure `texi2dvi` can't use `biber`? It compiles your MWE fine for me if I set `backend=biber`.

Comment: Pretty sure, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68141/texi2dvi-does-not-run-biber-bibtex (last change in `texi2dvi` dates back to 2004). Note that in the MWE above, I use `bibtex`. `biber` indeed compiles but I think it's simply ignored. At least I don't see any references/output unless I manually do `biber ...`.

Comment: `texi2dvi --version` gives me `texi2dvi (GNU Texinfo 6.5) 7906 Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.` And it definitely works. it runs `latex` and `biber` several times and I get a `dvi` file with a bibliography under each chapter.

Comment: Oh! The version on CTAN is well out of date. See http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/texinfo

Comment: Actually, even the version in CTAN which is 2014 supports `biber` and compiles your MWE fine for me.

Comment: ... fantastic, now this finally works. My TeXLive 2018 came with texi2dvi (GNU Texinfo 4.8) from 2004. No idea why the version is not updated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by updating `texi2dvi` to a more recent version.